# Form field (unique = true) and (nullable=true)

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, unique

I have one field in a form called 'discountCode' in relation with 'codiceSconto' in the User.php class.

```
//Discount.php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type= "integer", nullable = true) 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity= "User", mappedBy = "codiceSconto")
 */
 private discountCode;


//User.php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=5, nullable=true)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Discount", inversedBy="discountCode")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="codicesconto_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

private $codiceSconto;
```

It represents a discount code that the user could use to buy a product. 
It's not required.
I've set it to (unique = true) because every discount represents a discount percentage, so it must be unique. But I got an error when I try to validate the form saying that the discountCode field can't be NULL. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `nullable` option in join column.
Moreover you don't need to specify column type if you are in a relation with other entities. Checkout the following snippet of code

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity= "User", mappedBy = "discount")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
 private discountCode;
```

Comment: Mmh, didn't get it. I've edited the original question with the entire relation. I can't find the error.

Comment: @ZugZwang as I said here, you should put the `nullable` option in joinColumn and you should not declare the `Column` when you are in a relation situation. Please read again my answer.